# How to update ListView with BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, listview

I want update `ListView` from `BroadcastReceiver` in `onReceiver event`.

How to initialized `ListView` in this class then update to `ListView`:

```
public class CallBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int pState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                callDAO = new CallDAO(context);
                if (configPreferenceManager.getAutoRecord()) {
                    if (state != pState) {
                        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK && callInfoPreferenceManager.getCallState()) {
                            uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                                Uri.encode(callInfoPreferenceManager.getPhoneNumber()));
                            projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                                    , ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID
                            };


                            // START SERVICES TO RECORD CALL. AFTER IT, I WANT UPDATE MY LIST
                            sIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    CallRecordService.class);
                            context.startService(sIntent);
                        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING && callInfoPreferenceManager.getCallState()) {
                            callInfoPreferenceManager.setPhoneNumber(incomingNumber);
                            callInfoPreferenceManager.setSending(String.valueOf(false));

                        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE && callInfoPreferenceManager.getCallState() == CALLING) {
                                callDAO.insert(callInfoPreferenceManager.getName(),
                                    callInfoPreferenceManager.getPhoneNumber(),
                                    callInfoPreferenceManager.getStartDate()
                                            + configPreferenceManager.getPathFormat());
                            callDAO.close();

                            // Record call start service
                            sIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    CallRecordService.class);
                            context.stopService(sIntent);
                            callInfoPreferenceManager.setCallState(IDLE);

                        }
                        pState = state;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }//onReceive

}
```

In the code I posted is `BroadcastReceiver` class.

And I can't using `getActivity()` class or `findViewById(a, b)` when extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Start the activity that will populate the listview using Intents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,Myactivity.class)
startactivity(intent);
```

To avoid multiple instances of same 'Myactivity', use appropriate flags in the Manifest file.

If you want to transfer data between your broadcastReceiver and 'Myactivity', either use `intent.putExtra()` or store the data into `sharedPreferences`

Comment: Yes, I added this code: `sIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    CallRecordService.class);`
                           `context.startService(sIntent);`

Comment: but I don't know how to initialize `ListView` with activity

Comment: @JoeJoinshon, then you just need to read about using listview or recyclerviews.
Here is a link http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html